# Automatic call disconnects in Twilio

Tags: java, xml, scala, twilio, twilio-twiml

Automatic call disconnects in Twilio, and I think this is the reason:

controller

```
var lng="en-US";
var code="123456"
var twiml="<Say voice='alice' language='"+lng+"'>";
twiml+=Messages("callData", "","</Say><Pause length='1'/><Say voice='alice'>"+code.toList.mkString("</Say><Pause length='1'/><Say voice='alice'>"))(Lang(lng))+"</Say>"
Ok(views.xml.twilio(twiml))
```

twilio.scala.xml

```
@(twiml:String)
<Response>@twiml</Response>
```

But this is not working properly. 
 
It shows the content but not as like xml, where Response tag shown in purple color and the string that I entered is in black.

When I check the Body of request in Request Inspector in my Twilio account, it shows me something like this.

```
&lt;Say voice=&apos;alice&apos;&gt;4&lt;/Say&gt;
```

I know its not a proper way to deal with xml.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it takes the xml as string. if you can define the content type it should work. 
like

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
```